# How to Add Relationship to a Timeline?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have Custom Entity A with a lookup  (Entity Account)

I want to See all Tasks related to the Account in the Timeline from Entity A

I have a Custom relationship between Entity A an Task (1-N)

I have A Flow (Power Automate) Who triggered When a new Task is created (filter Regarding is of Type Account):
if there is a Record my Entity A who have a relation with This Account so I Relate My Record with this Task .

Everything is Working perfectly.

Problem is that I cannot see the related Tasks in my A entity Timeline!

Is it Possible to add a Custom relationship to the Timeline to see the task there?

The customer absolutely wants to see the tasks in the timeline and not in a subgrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Not possible in an OOB way to add timeline from custom lookup/relationship. The timeline requires a direct relationship, that too either as an activity regarding or in activity party list.

Let’s say, you have a phone call activity, you can add this custom entity lookup value in callTo activity party list, as the account is already in regarding and a contact maybe in callFrom activity party, this phoncall will be in timeline of account, contact and custom entity (which was activity enabled and/or having email field to act as activity party)

OOB Task does not involve multiple parties and has tight integration with Outlook task. So a custom task activity will work in your case.

Alternate better choice, develop a custom timeline control using PCF (React + typescript) and use whatever api/fetchxml queries to gather related Tasks list and populate your PCF timeline. :)

PowerApps Component Framework (PCF) is reusable control, helps to achieve whatever used to be achieved using HTML web resource scenarios.